# Whirlpool Duet front loader door won't unlock

Tags: washing-machine

I have a Whirlpool Duet front loading washer.  It finished its cycle, all the lights are off, no error codes, but the door won't unlock.  I unplugged it and let it sit.  Then I found a manual online that said to remove the toe panel and pull a manual release.  I think I found it but the lock still won't open.  I tried running through the diagnostic cycle and didn't get any error codes and it makes the usual sound it makes when it locks and unlocks.  Any other ideas?  I belive it's one of these 2 models: GHW9100L or GHW9200L

Comment: There may be a problem with water drainage. Take a look at this: `https://homeguides.sfgate.com/unlock-whirlpool-duet-washing-machine-68645.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After letting it sit overnight unplugged, the manual release worked.  Problem solved...now on to figuring out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what fixed the immediate problem. Please be sure to give yourself a check mark for the answer so others will be able to find out how to unlock theirs.